# Do we create "stub" or "signpost" duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates

**Do we ever create "intentional duplicates" for questions that have not been explicitly asked, but which have answers in other, related questions?**

**Case in point**

There are several posts in which polychords are explained; however, there is no "What is a polychord?" question. A user searching for "what is a polychord" and reading through the search results will eventually find an answer, but it seems (potentially) more efficient to have a direct question, if only to point -- by way of being closed as a duplicate -- to a post with a good answer.

**What are the SE philosophy and MP&T community opinion in this regard?**

Maybe a simple answer in this case is to create a [polychord](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polychord) tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a canonical question for "What is a polychord?" would make the most sense. A tag may make sense in the long run, but if the goal is to answer and link an underlying question rather than create a needed category of questions, I'd shy away from the tag.

Comment: So does it make sense to create the question, but then immediately vote to close it as a duplicate of one of the others that has a good answer? Or is it better to include a "canonical" answer and then just link to the other questions?

Comment: @Aaron It would make more sense to have a very good and in depth canonical question and answer. We'll worry about the duplicates after we have that.