# List of topics having, or in need of, a solid, well-researched canonical post

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates, canonical-q-a

## Finding/Creating a Canonical Post

When you find or create a Q&A that you feel is a good canonical Q&A for some topic, nominate it with a Meta post. Get a score of 10 or more, and it's canon. Create an answer to this question to track the topic, the canonical post, and the duplicate/related posts. Please also remove the topic from the below list, if present.

**If you find a topic that could use a good canonical post, please add it to the list below.**

---

## List of Common Topics Needing a Canonical Post

- Use of bVII in "backdoor progression"
- Polychords (meta discussion here: [Do we create “stub” or “signpost” duplicate questions?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/do-we-create-stub-or-signpost-duplicate-questions))
- "Too many notes in a measure": there are a variety of questions along this line. Canonical answer could include [grace notes/ornaments](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/51888/why-am-i-seeing-more-notes-than-allowed-to-be-in-a-bar), [multiple simultaneous voices](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/53041/too-many-notes-in-this-measure), [cadenzas](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/102248/why-arent-there-barlines-in-the-piano-solo-parts-in-beethovens-piano-concerto), [changing meaning of time signatures](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/108980/time-signatures-and-values-exceeding-the-bar), perhaps others.
- Putting steel or nylon strings on a nylon- or steel-string guitar. As of 3 Feb 2021, there are 39 questions found by the query "nylon steel is:question". A quick perusal suggests around a dozen that are variations on the same question.
- Basic "Time-signature" questions: see [Should I just go and make a community wiki about time signatures?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3760/70803)

---

## Format for answers to this post

1. Subject header
2. Link to canonical post
3. List of duplicate posts
4. List of related posts

### Example

```
# bVII chords used in "backdoor progression"

* **Link to outstanding, well-researched post on the subject**

### Duplicates
* Link to duplicate #1
* Link to duplicate #2
* Etc.

### Closely related
* Link to related post #1
* Link to related post #2
* Etc.
```

---

## See Also

- [Proposed method for nominating/selecting canonical posts](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/should-we-create-a-faq-about-music-theory/3549#3549)

#### Related discussions

- [Question Cleanup: Could we curate a list of questions with good answers on common topics?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2968/question-cleanup-could-we-curate-a-list-of-questions-with-good-answers-on-commo)
- [Should we create a FAQ about Music Theory?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2968/question-cleanup-could-we-curate-a-list-of-questions-with-good-answers-on-commo)

Answer (score 0):

## Confusion over multiple voices scored on a single staff

[Rest above a note in a piano piece](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/15929/70803)

#### Duplicates

- [List of linked questions](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/15929?lq=1) (includes dupes and closely related)

#### Closely related

See "Duplicates", above