# Should I just go and make a community wiki about time signatures?

Tags: discussion

I seem to be repeating myself regularly when questions about time-signatures come up. Should we not just make a big community thread composing of all the related time-signatures and point askers towards it?

It should not be so hard and would keep this scatter-gun approach to time signatures that we currently have from continuing to repeat itself

Comment: Repeating ourselves regularly would suggest lots of duplicates. Perhaps a (set of) canonical question(s) already exists?

Comment: FWIW, I've been keeping a community wiki here on Meta listing [topics that could use a canonical Q&A](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3634/70803). I've added "time signatures", but some additional notes on what such a post should contain would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

If one of those questions about time signature is well written, has good answer(s) and can be used as a canonical answer, then the best course of action is to start marking/closing the other questions as duplicates of it.

If we can't identify one (or maybe a small number), **then** it may be appropriate to create a question specifically designed to have a comprehensive answer. Community wiki is mostly deprecated these days across the network.

Comment: Is the deprecation of community wiki a de facto reality (users simply don't create/maintain them), or a (semi-)official position (their is some implicit or explicit intention to move away from them)?

Comment: SE stated their intent to move away from them, yes. I’ll try to find the meta.SE post when back at a computer (not easy on mobile)